# Lightbox stuck on loading image for one set of images

Tags: php, html, lightbox

I am using lightbox on one of my pages, and it wont load one of my sets o images.  I don't know  if there are any known compatibility issues, but I have tried the same images exported in several different methods, including methods that are already working on the page. I have three sections of images right now which are as follows

HTML:

```
<h1 id="collapseGallery" class="collapse" data-image-id="galleryImg">Contemporary Issues in Painting: Digital Media</h1>

            <div id="galleryImg" class="hide">
                <ul> <?php include 'imagesCIPD.php'; ?> </ul>
            </div>
            <h1 id="collapseGallery2" class="collapse" data-image-id="galleryImg2">Contemporary Issues in Painting: Traditional Media</h1>
            <div id="galleryImg2" class="hide">
                <ul> <?php include 'imagesCIPT.php'; ?> </ul>
            </div>
            <h1 id="collapseGallery3" class="collapse" data-image-id="galleryImg3">Russian & Soviet History</h1>
            <div id="galleryImg3" class="hide">
                <ul> <?php include 'imagesCONS.php'; ?> </ul>
            </div>
```

These are collapsible sections, and the images display on the page fine until I try to load them through lightbox.  The first two sections, Digital and Traditional media work fine with no issues, but the last set, in Russian and Soviet History will not load in ligthbox.

Here is a reference of the php files that are used to load the images from two of the sets

Traditional Prints:

```
  echo "<a href='images/school/contemporaryIssuesInPainting/traditional/".$result_ar['fileName']."' data-lightbox='CIPT'><img style='width: 22%; height: auto;' src='images/school/contemporaryIssuesInPainting/traditional/".$result_ar['fileName']."' ></a>";
}
```

And the section that is failing, R&S History:

```
echo "<a href='images/school/contructivism/".$result_ar['fileName']."' data-lightbox='CONS' ><img style='width: 22%; height: auto;' src='images/school/constructivism/".$result_ar['fileName']."' ></a>";
```

}

I have looked over the files several times, and can't find any discrepancies, but maybe I just need a second pair of eyes... Can anyone see where the issue is?

Comment: Can't seem to find anything wrong from here. Could you post the javascript code and PHP of `imagesCONS.php` too?

Comment: What happens when you try to open the lightbox? You can use Chrome's Developer Tools (built-in to Chrome: Ctrl-Shift-I) to check if there are any script errors. Errors will come up as a small x in a red circle on the top right of the Developer Tools snap-in. Click on it to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger  The R&S History code is the imagesCONS.php, I should have made that clear sorry.  And yeah, do you want all my javascript or just lightbox?  @shrmn  It gets stuck on its built in loader .gif.  Ill check out the dev tool though, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Okay, I spelled constructionist wrong. The dev tools helped, showed right up.  Thanks for the help ya'll.